# How to optimize code removing unwanted characters

Tags: ruby

This code is designed for a problem where the users computer has a bug where every time he/she hits the backspace button it displays a '<' symbol. The created program should fix this and output the intended string considering that '<' represents a backspace. The input string can be up to 10^6 characters long, and it only will include lowercase letters and '<'.

My code seems to be executing correctly but, when I submit it, the website says it exceeded the time limit for test 5/25. The amount of time given is 1 second. Also, if there are only '<' symbols it should produce no output.

For example,

```
"hellooo<< my name is matthe<<"
```

would output

```
"hello my name is matt"
```

and

```
"ssadfas<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"
```

would output nothing, etc.

Here is the code:

```
input = gets.chomp
while input[/[[:lower:]]</]
    input.gsub!(/[[:lower:]]</, "")
end
input.gsub!(/</, "")
puts"#{input}"
```

In the code above I stay in the `while` loop if there are any instances where a lowercase letter is in front of a '<'. Anywhere a lowercase letter is followed by a '<' it is replaced with nothing. Once the `while` loop is exited if there are any '<' symbols left, they are replaced with nothing. Then the final string is displayed.

I created a test which I think is worst case scenario for my code:

```
input = ("a" + "<" + "a")*10000000

#input = gets.chomp
while input[/[[:lower:]]</]
    input.gsub!(/[[:lower:]]</, "")
end
input.gsub!(/</, "")
puts"#{input}"
```

I made the program stop between the creation of the string and the execution of the `while` loop and then ran it completely to be able to eyeball if it was taking longer than a second. It seemed to take much longer than 1 second.

How can it be modified to be faster or is there a much better way to do this?

Comment: You said the input can be up to 10^6 characters, but you seem to be testing against 3 * 10^7? When I run your code against input that's 10^6 characters long on my laptop, it takes about a third of a second.

Comment: The strings contain spaces as well as lowercase letters and '<'. Does backspace delete a space? Best to edit to clarify.

Comment: Attempt #3.....

Comment: First, an unanchored regular expression is much slower than built-in methods. Anchor it and it improves in speed. Let the engine remove as much as possible in one step and it gets faster still, but it possibly still won't run as fast as methods written in C. `gsub` is slower than `sub`, but faster than looping over `sub`. Learn to use Benchmark, Fruity or Benchmark-ips as they're your eyes into the efficiency of your code.

Comment: @smarx yea, that was a dumb mistake, good catch on the 3*10^7. However, there must be another case that is the worst case scenario or its getting stuck in the loop because the program exceeds the time limit

Comment: @theTinMan thanks I will try that

Answer (score 2):

```
def backspace(str)
  bs_count = 0
  str.reverse.each_char.with_object([]) do |s, arr|
    if s == '<'
      bs_count += 1
    else
      bs_count.zero? ? arr.unshift(s) : bs_count -= 1
    end
  end.join
end

backspace "Now is the<< tim<e fo<<<r every<<<one to chill ou<<<<t"
  #=> "Now is t tier evone to chilt"
```

Comment: I haven't tested it, but does this really show a substantial performance improvement over the original code? (My intuition is that it would be slower.)

Comment: Well, it makes just a single pass through the string.

Comment: When I test with `output = ("a" + "<" + "a")*330000` (about 10^6 characters), the code in the question runs in about a third of a second, and I killed your code after a minute. With 10^5 characters, the original code takes 0.144s, and yours takes 1.761s.

Comment: FYI, your code eventually completed after ~3.5 minutes with the 10^6 character input. I think the issue is the `s[i,2] = ''`. I suspect the implementation of that operation is expensive (and probably linear with the size of the string).

Comment: For `n = 3`, `('a' * n + '<' * n) * n #=> "aaa<<<aaa<<<aaa<<<"`. Try comparing the methods for `n = 50`. I expect you are right about `[]=` being expensive. I have an idea for an improvement. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Note the above comments all pertain to code that I've replaced in my answer.

Comment: What's the timing on your latest version? It looks very similar to my first pass, which turned out to be almost twice as slow as the original code.

Comment: @smartx, here I build a string rather than deleting characters from a string. Please see Peter's benchmark.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was comparing to something more like `better_method`. I think my take was also a little slower for using a string rather than an array to build up the output.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is good but you get better performance if you adapt the regular expression.

Cary, I hope you don't mind I take your excellent solution also in the benchmark ?

Benchmark done on a MRI ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x64-mingw32]
I use .dup on my sample string to make sure none of the methods changes the input sample.

```
require 'benchmark' 
input = ""
10_000_000.times{input << ['a','<'].sample}

def original_method inp
  while inp[/[[:lower:]]</]
    inp.gsub!(/[[:lower:]]</, "")
  end
  inp.gsub(/</, "")
end

def better_method inp
  tuple = /[^<]</
  while inp[tuple]
    inp.gsub!(inp[tuple], "")
  end
  inp.gsub(/</, "")
end

def backspace str
  bs_count = 0
  str.reverse.each_char.with_object([]) do |s, arr|
    if s == '<'
      bs_count += 1
    else
      bs_count.zero? ? arr.unshift(s) : bs_count -= 1
    end
  end.join
end

puts original_method(input.dup).length
puts better_method(input.dup).length
puts backspace(input.dup).length

Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report("original_method")  { original_method(input.dup) }
  x.report("backspace      ")  { backspace(input.dup) }
  x.report("better_method  ")  { better_method(input.dup) }
end
```

gives

```
3640
3640
3640
       user     system      total        real
original_method  3.494000   0.016000   3.510000 (  3.510709)
backspace        1.872000   0.000000   1.872000 (  1.862550)
better_method    1.155000   0.031000   1.186000 (  1.187495)
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark, Peter. Naturally, the results depend on the test input. Here are two that I ran (where I show only the last column of the benchmark). For `input = 'a<' * 250000` (`"a<a<a<..."`) I got `original_method: 0.044, backspace: 0.129, better_method 0.025`. For
`input = ('a' * 500 + '<' * 500) * 500` (`"aa...aa<<...<<aa...aa<<...<<..."`) I got `original_method: 2.29; backspace 0.12: better_method 0.26`. "better_method" is an interesting name for your method (`:-)`), but it does look hard to beat.

Comment: I assume you displayed `puts original_method(input.dup).size #=> 3640` (etc.) to suggest all three methods gave the same result. Other options are `puts original_method(input.dup).hash #=> -968494489149926863`  (etc.) and `puts [original_method(input.dup), backspace(input.dup), better_method(input.dup)].uniq.size`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the follow up Cary, in this case I wanted it KISS but your suggestions for checking result are better, as for the name better_method, wasn't meant at yours :>) but compared with the original_method, I added yours later on. The sample is indeed determent for the results, thats why I took a random solution and ran it many times, which I could obviously not do with the 10MB sample, in all cases I tested the results were comparable but I'm sure better_method won't always be the fastest

Comment: @peter thanks! This code still exceeds the time limit, maybe I am missing something in the problem statement that is causing this error. This was just something I was doing on my free time and its making me frustrated haha. Here is the link... **https://open.kattis.com/problems/backspace** . Maybe you can find what is causing this >1sec run time. Thanks everyone for the help. I really enjoy becoming more efficient with ruby

Comment: multiple remarks on that: speed depends on the input and what was the  input ? the examples of a few words or a really random string of 10MB ? 2: depends also of Ruby implementation, jRuby got it down to 1.2s on my 4 year old windows box, the best result I got with compiling with ocra to .exe, just under 1 sec 3:depends on the CPU this is run, I have no experience with kattis so didn't try